# How the wavelength of a photon is affected by an uniform gravitational field

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, coordinate-systems, equivalence-principle, gravitational-redshift

In the presence of a uniform gravitational field two observers at fixed positions obtain different measurements of frequency of the same photon. One observer at the origin of some coordinate system measure $\nu_1$ and one at fixed position $x$ in the same coordinate chart measure $\nu_2$. The relation is

$$\nu_2  = \nu_1 \left( 1 + \frac{\phi}{c^2} \right) \tag1$$

Where the potential difference is $\phi \le 0$, such that $\nu_2 \le \nu_1$. However in Einstein's 1911 paper *" On the Influence of Gravitation on the Propagation of Light"*, there is a formula for the speed of light that each observer obtain. If the observer that measures $\nu_1$ also measures $c_0$ and the observer that measures $\nu_2$ also measures $c$ we have the formula

$$c = c_0 \left( 1 + \frac{\phi}{c^2}\right) $$.

My point is: how the wavelength of the photon should change between these observers? Comparing the two formulas, I'm attempted to think that the observers agree about the measurement of wavelength, but since the frequency changes, the wavelength should also be different for each measurement. Where is my mistake?

Comment: It is good to keep always in mind that light emerges from the quantum mechanical level of photons, but photons are not light. They have energy h*nu, where nu is the frequency of the emergent light from very many photons, but the photons have no wavelength, they are point particles https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle

Comment: @annav thank you so much, this comments helped me a lot. However, if I change "photon" to " a light beam" in my question, would this problem remain?

Comment: it would make it consistent with the answer, and with the fact you ask of measuring wavelengths.

Comment: you do not ask if gravitational force acts differently on different wavelengths (thus energies) of photons? As this is understood?

Answer (score 2):

Why are you reading and taking seriously a paper from 1911? Einstein   had not yet understand the interplay between gravity and time.

The formula you quote for for the speed of light is now known to be the speed in *coordinate time*. The *actual* speed of light measured by a clock is $c$ for all observers everywhere. The relation $\lambda \nu=c$ holds for all observers so a reduction in frequency is accompanied by an increase in wavelength.

Comment: So the "transformation" of the wavelength need to be consistent only with eq. (1) and not with the speed of light equation?

Comment: You should ignore the misleading (i.e wrong) "speed of light equation."

Answer (score 2):

Consider a different approach, start from the geodesic equation for light rays:

$$P^{\nu}\nabla_{\nu}P^{\mu}=\frac{dP^{\mu}}{d\tau}+\Gamma^{\mu}_{\rho\nu}P^{\rho}P^{\nu}=0$$ where $P^{\mu}=\frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\tau}=(E,p,0,0)$ (say) is the 4-momentum of photon with $E=p$. Now use the de-Broglie relation $$p=\frac{h}{\lambda}$$ and substitute this into the above equation to obtain the evolution of wave-length $\lambda$ between two points on a given geodesic (On solving this equation, you can obtain $\lambda=\lambda(\tau)$, $\tau$ being the affine parameter on the null geodesic). Sometimes, the space-time may admit Killing  vector fields $K^{\mu}$, corresponding to which we have the quantities $Q_K=K^{\mu}P_{\mu}$ conserved along the null geodesics ($P^{\mu}\nabla_{\mu}Q=0$). These conserved quantities may simplify the expression for $\lambda=\lambda(\tau)$

Generally, given a 4-momentum vector $P^{\mu}\sim (\omega, \textbf{k})$, the net wave-number as measured by the observer (with a velocity field $U^{\mu}$) is $|k|^2=\frac{1}{\lambda^2}\sim -h_{\mu\nu}P^{\mu}P^{\nu}$, where $h_{\mu\nu}=g_{\mu\nu}-U_{\mu}U_{\nu}$ is the induced metric on the three dimensional surface orthogonal to $U^{\mu}$.

We may assume that velocity field of the observer is geodetic and affine w.r.t some parameter $\sigma$. For a constant gravitational field, you can construct an approximate metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ such that it satisfies (in the non-relativistic limit):
$$\ddot{x}^i=\frac{dU^i}{d\sigma}\approx-\Gamma^{i}_{00}(U^0)^2=g^i$$ i=1,2,3 and $g^i$ are the components of constant gravitational field.

Comment: Is light deflected, deviated by gravitational force depending on its wavelenght? Blue light is deflected by the earth  in a different angle? (like in Rayleigh scattering)

Comment: @PeterBernhard In principle, yes. We need to provide the initial data $P^a_0\sim (\omega, k^i)$ at some time $\tau=\tau_0$ and let it evolve following geodesic equation. If the problem is well-posed, different initial data will correspond to different geodesics.